# Problemas al poner video en modal Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, html5, bootstrap

Buenas tardes tengo un problema con la implementación de una modal que reproduce un video que vi en el siguiente [link](https://codepen.io/JacobLett/pen/xqpEYE) intente replicarlo pero no me queda, solo abre la modal pero no se ve el video.

> Este es mi código

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

// Gets the video src from the data-src on each button

var $videoSrc;
$('.video-btn').click(function() {
    $videoSrc = $(this).data( "src" );
});
console.log($videoSrc);

// when the modal is opened autoplay it
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {

// set the video src to autoplay and not to show related video. Youtube related video is like a box of chocolates... you never know what you're gonna get
$("#video").attr('src',$videoSrc + "?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;autoplay=1" );
})

// stop playing the youtube video when I close the modal
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    // a poor man's stop video
    $("#video").attr('src',$videoSrc);
})

// document ready
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
 <div id="abacomCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" >
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">


      <div class="modal-body">

       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="" id="video"  allowscriptaccess="always">></iframe>
</div>


      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>


   <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div class="carousel-item active bg-queretaro bg-general">
   <!--a href="/inicio-operaciones/" target="_blank" class="asd"-->
    <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="<?=base_url()?>images/carousel/abacom.jpg" alt="Internet Satelital en Querétaro" width="100%">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-10 offset-md-6 offset-sm-2 offset-1 text-carousel text-center">
     <h3>¡Bienvenido a Querétaro!</mark></h3>
     <p>Muchas empresas nacionales  y extranjeras  se instalan en Querétaro cada mes y  en Abacom sabemos lo importante que es arrancar sin contratiempos.</p>
     <p>Permita a Abacom ser su aliado tecnológico y apoye con expertos en conectividad de su empresa. Conozca como hemos ayudado a otras empresas en sus inicios<a href="<?=base_url()?>index.php/abacom/testimoniales"  class="dark-blue"><mark>aquí</mark></a>e imagine lo que podemos hacer por usted.</p>
    </div>
   <!--/a-->
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item bg-redundancia bg-general">
     <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="<?=base_url()?>images/carousel/abacom.jpg" alt="Internet Empresarial" width="100%">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-10 offset-md-0 offset-sm-2 offset-1 text-carousel text-center">
    <h3>CONTINUIDAD: Siempre conectado</h3>
    <p>Abacom entrega un circuito de internet por fibra óptica y otro enlace de internet por microondas TOTALMENTE GRATIS.</p>
    <p>Porqué en Abacom sabemos que las mejores prácticas en su empresa es contar con una redundancia por otro medio  que permita dar continuidad a su operación.</p>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item bg-conectividad bg-general" title="Abacom" onclick="window.open('https://www.abacom.mx/inicio-operaciones/')">
  <!--a href="/inicio-operaciones/" target="_blank" class="asd"-->
   <img class="d-block2 img-fluid" src="<?=base_url()?>images/carousel/abacom.jpg" alt="Internet Ilimitado" width="100%">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-10 col-10 offset-md-0 offset-sm-2 offset-1 text-carousel text-center"  >
    <h3>Comienza con el pie derecho: ¡Conectividad es lo primero!</h3>
    <p>Permítenos resolver tus necesidades inmediatas de comunicación, si necesitas arrancar nosotros te  podemos ayudar:</p>
    <ul class="ul-conectividad text-left">
     <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i> Internet dedicado instalado en 6 días</li>
     <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i> Conmutadores que crecen a la par de tu operación</li>
     <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i> Telefonía a la medida</li>
     <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i> Implementación de redes WiFi y redes alámbricas</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  <!--/a-->
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item bg-solucion bg-general" title="Abacom">
    <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="<?=base_url()?>images/carousel/abacom.jpg" title="Internet Empresarial" alt="Internet Satelital en Querétaro" width="100%" >
   <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-8 col-10 offset-md-7 offset-sm-2 offset-1 text-carousel text-center">
    <h3 title="Internet Satelital en Querétaro">Somos la solución para los desarrolladores y clusters industriales</h3>
    <p>Abacom se especializa en ecosistemas de conectividad en clusters empresariales para generar soluciones a la medida</p>
   </div>
  </div>
   </div>
   <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#abacomCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
   </a>
   <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#abacomCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
   </a>
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#abacomCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#abacomCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#abacomCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  <li data-target="#abacomCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  <!--
  <div class="arrow-down ad" link="#solucion">
   <small class=white title="Internet Empresarial">Encuentra una solución</small><br>
   <img src="<?=base_url()?>images/btn-abacom.gif" alt="down">
  </div>-->
   </ol>
 </div>
</div>
<!-- services  -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<div class="spacer feature24 ">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Row -->
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-7 text-center">
                <h2 class="title font-light">¿Buscas una solución? Te vamos a acompañar en este recorrido</h2>
                <h6 class="subtitle">Ofreciéndote la mejor solución que se adapte a tus necesidades.</h6>
                <div class="m-t-40">
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-inverse btn-rounded btn-md btn-arrow m-t-20" href="https://syntaxtecnologias.com.mx/index.php/Inicio_controller/servicios"><span>Ver servicios<i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Row -->
        <div class="row m-t-30 p-t-30 client-box">
            <!-- column  -->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6" style="text-align: center;">
                <div class="no-block contador">
                    <i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-3x"></i>
                    <div class="m-l-20">
                        <h3 class="font-light counter m-b-0">5000</h3>
                        <h6 class="text-muted font-13 text-uppercase">Clientes Felices</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- column  -->
            <!-- column  -->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6" style="text-align: center;">
                <div class="no-block contador">
                    <i class="fa fa-coffee fa-3x"></i>
                    <div class="m-l-20">
                        <h3 class="font-light counter m-b-0">20</h3>
                        <h6 class="text-muted font-13 text-uppercase">Años de experiencia</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- column  -->
            <!-- column  -->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6" style="text-align: center;">
                <div class="no-block contador">
                    <i class="fa fa-users fa-3x"></i>
                    <div class="m-l-20">
                        <h3 class="font-light counter m-b-0">200</h3>
                        <h6 class="text-muted font-13 text-uppercase">Personal dedicado</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- column  -->
            <!-- column  -->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6" style="text-align: center;">
                <div class="no-block contador">
                    <i class="fa fa-trophy fa-3x"></i>
                    <div class="m-l-20">
                        <h3 class="font-light counter m-b-0">20</h3>
                        <h6 class="text-muted font-13 text-uppercase">Premios ganados</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- column  -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- services   -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<section>
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
     <div class="col-md-12 nopadding">
      <div class="ce-feature-box-10">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary video-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Jfrjeg26Cwk" data-target="#myModal">
        Play Video 1
     </button>
        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
       <div class="content pos-1">
        <h2 class="font-weight-6 less-mar-1 line-height-5 text-white">Conexión de Vanguardia</h2>
       </div>
      <img src="http://codelayers.net/templates/consep/images/46.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"/>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</section>

<div class="row" id="solucion">
 <div class="col-12 text-center solucion" title="Internet Satelital">
  <h1>¿Buscas una solución?</h1>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-12 text-center cuestionario">
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="row" id="experto">
    <div class="col-12">
     <h1 id="pregunta"></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="col-8 offset-2">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 text-center">
       <h2><mark id="opcion1" next="" class="opex">Si</mark></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
       <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-8 col-12 offset-md-4 offset-sm-2 offset-0">
        <h2>
         <mark id="opcion3" next="" class="opex">
         </mark>
        </h2>
        <i class="fa fa-search fa-4x"></i>


       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 text-center">
       <h2><mark id="opcion2" next="" class="opex">No</mark></h2>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
     <br>
     <button class="btn btn-primary" id="back-exp">Regresar</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

Este es el error que me manda cuando copio el código del JS, Pensé que era por los signos de $, pero noté que es cuando pongo código en las etiquetas JS.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Saludos.

Comment: tienes incluido la libreria jquery en tu html, porque generalmente este error se da por ello..!!

Comment: referenceError: $ is not defined... define tu jquery..porque en tu script que muestras contiene jquery

Comment: si lo tengo añadido porque tambien no le abriría la modal